# Error when running deepmind

Tags: theano

It took me two days to install the requirements of deepQ(python version),then I tried to run it today but I faced this problem, and the code are as followed.

```
root@unicorn:/media/trump/Data1/wei/college/laboratory/deep_q_rl-master/deep_q_rl# python run_nips.py
A.L.E: Arcade Learning Environment (version 0.5.0)
[Powered by Stella]
Use -help for help screen.
Warning: couldn't load settings file: ./ale.cfg
Game console created:
ROM file:  ../roms/breakout.bin
Cart Name: Breakout - Breakaway IV (1978) (Atari)
Cart MD5:  f34f08e5eb96e500e851a80be3277a56
Display Format:  AUTO-DETECT ==> NTSC
ROM Size:        2048
Bankswitch Type: AUTO-DETECT ==> 2K

Running ROM file...
Random seed is 65
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_nips.py", line 60, in <module>
launcher.launch(sys.argv[1:], Defaults, __doc__)
File "/media/trump/Data1/wei/college/laboratory/deep_q_rl-master/deep_q_rl/launcher.py", line 223, in launch
rng)
File "/media/trump/Data1/wei/college/laboratory/deep_q_rl-master/deep_q_rl/q_network.py", line 53, in __init__
num_actions, num_frames, batch_size)
File "/media/trump/Data1/wei/college/laboratory/deep_q_rl-master/deep_q_rl/q_network.py", line 168, in build_network
batch_size)
File "/media/trump/Data1/wei/college/laboratory/deep_q_rl-master/deep_q_rl/q_network.py", line 407, in build_nips_network_dnn
from lasagne.layers import dnn
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Lasagne-0.2.dev1-py2.7.egg/lasagne/layers/dnn.py", line 13, in <module>
raise ImportError("dnn not available")  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: dnn not available
```

I have already tested theano ,numpy, scipy and there was no errors coming out. But when I ran it, it said dnn not available. So I came to find dnn, and the code is like this

```
import theano
from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn

from .. import init
from .. import nonlinearities
from .base import Layer

from .conv import conv_output_length
from .pool import pool_output_length
from ..utils import as_tuple

if not theano.config.device.startswith("gpu") or not dnn.dnn_available():
    raise ImportError("dnn not available")  # pragma: no cover
```

Just hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you using `device=gpu` in your `THEANO_FLAGS`?

Comment: No, I do not know that I should do this, I will have a try. Can you tell me how to do that with more details? Where and how I can do that?

Comment: I can not understand the documentation of theano, I am still do not know how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install CUDA and cuDNN? 
Lasagne is build on top of Theano and is, in some cases, relying on cuda code (e.g. here), rather than abstracting it away.

This can be seen from the import:

```
from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn
```

Also see: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/242

To get cuDNN you need to register at NVidia as a developer, see:
https://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have reinstalled it, which had not finished yet.

Comment: I do not know, in fact my Ubuntu failed to log in again, sometimes it just stop at the logo window, but I still do not know why.

Comment: I installed cuda firstly with nvidia driver installed. Then I installed theano, mayby I forgot to change the path.